# 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Class to an unrelated type flash.data:SQLConnection

Tags: android, sqlite, apache-flex, flash-builder

am trying to create new record for my local  sqlite database using this code
but it dosent work, when i click save i get this error

1120: `Access of undefined property sqlConnection.`

this is my method in the EmployeeDAO

```
          public static function  create(employee:Employee):void
    {

    var sql:String = "INSERT INTO words (id, term, defin, term1, defin1) " +
            "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
        stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
        stmt.text = sql;

        stmt.parameters[1] = employee.term;
        stmt.parameters[2] = employee.defin;
        stmt.parameters[3] = employee.term1;
        stmt.execute();
        employee.loaded = false;
    }
```

add.mxml where i try to save record to database

```
    import model.Employee;
    import model.EmployeeDAO;

        protected function onSave():void {

            var newEmployee:Employee = new Employee();
            newEmployee.term = term.text;
            newEmployee.defin = defin.text;
            newEmployee.term1 = term1.text;
            newEmployee.defin1 = defin1.text;
            EmployeeDAO.create(newEmployee);
            navigator.popView();
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:actionContent>
    <s:Button label="Save" click="onSave()"/>
</s:actionContent>

<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10"/>
</s:layout>

<s:Label text="term"/>
<s:TextInput id="term" width="100%"/>

<s:Label text="defin"/>
<s:TextArea id="defin" width="100%" height="200"/>

<s:Label text="term1"/>
<s:TextInput id="term1" width="100%"/>

<s:Label text="defin1"/>
<s:TextArea id="defin1" width="100%" height="200"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your function  as static if you want to call it without instantiating the class. Then it will work

```
public static function  create(employee:Employee):void
```

Comment: Surely it will give error. As per your code sqlconnection is not defined. If you have defined sqlConnection outside the static function then it should also be defined as static.

Comment: but i cant define it more than once, already did "public function get sqlConnection():SQLConnection"

Comment: define it as public static function get sqlConnection():SQLConnection

Comment: it dosent recognize  create function in  EmployeeDAO.create(newEmployee);

Comment: can you post your latest code snippet, so that i can better understand the problem